# Customising element name of entries in an XML-serialised HashSet<string>

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-3.5, deserialization, webmethod

We could really use some help with a hashset output question. We have the HashSet web method working perfectly with HashSet except for one thing. The output is a webservice and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost/webservices">
    <string>201210XXXX</string>
    <string>201211XXXX</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

That's perfect except the customer requested the output of the lines of strings be lines of "TN" and "/TN" tags instead of the string tags. Figured this should be pretty easy and added my extra class but I cannot figure out how to do this

```
HashSet<TN>;
```

We built the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public HashSet<string> GetFoneLines()
{
    HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();

    DataTable dt = new dal().GetPhoneLines();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        hs.Add(dr[0].ToString());    
    }

    return hs;
}
```

and tried to extend the string class. Learning String is sealed, we just attempted to create our own class

```
public class TN
{
    public string tnumber;
}
```

This must be simple but after 48 hours of pounding out code I cant see how to create a Hash of TN's instead of a Hash of strings.

Comment: There is no TN in the XML sample.

Comment: Give your question a **meaningful** title please.

Comment: So what do you get when you serialize?  And do you have to return a HashSet via your web method?  Because I very much doubt that an ArrayOfString with TN elements is going to deserialize into a HashSet. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: Looks like you're serializing `string[]` not `TN` or `TN[]`. Also TN is definitely bad name for a class.

Comment: I need to add a type for HashSet that acts like a String but the output tags should be    <tn>201211xxxx</tn>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to decorate your class with custom XML serialization attributes like so:

```
public class TN
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="TN")]
    public string tnumber;

}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/athddy89.aspx).

Comment: Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'WebService1.TN' I like it but getting an error

Comment: Having trouble getting TN to act like or be an extention to String.

Comment: @Agrapha: When do you get such error? And what do you mean under "an extension"? During serialization or in C# code?

Comment: Wow what a difference sleep can give a person. The problem is what I'm populating the HASHSET with. Look at the webmethod. The line in the foreach "hs.Add(dr[0].ToString());" If I make a TN object and ask the hash to hash it thats ok but what I try to fill it with is a ToString()... What I realy need is a .ToTN() method.

Comment: Sadly it took me 2 years to see the simplicity of this suggestion. Why I didn't see the elegence of your answer before, I don't know. So simple, and elegant. I should have checked your answer correct.

Comment: @Agrapha: This very nice comment, thank you, I'm glad I was able to help :)